# How do I filter a nested array to display in a navigation list?

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, swiftui, filter

I have a Json File called customerData filled with a nested array. When I am displaying this I want to filter the array that is nested inside the first Array. I have already filtered the first array.

The flow of data goes from customerData.json to Customer.swift to `ModelData.swift` to `Dashboard.swift`.

I included a photo of my display.

Here is my Json data called `customerData`:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Michael",
        "id": 101,
        "category": "Admin",
        "isFeatured": true,
        
        "staff":[
            {
                "firstName": "Zeus",
                "lastName": "Lightening",
                "id": 106,
                "day": "Tuesday",
                "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Poseidon",
                "lastName": "Sea",
                "id": 107,
                "day": "Sunday",
                "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Caleb",
        "id": 102,
        "category": "Tech",
        "isFeatured": true,
        
        "staff":[
            {
                "firstName": "Hera",
                "lastName": "marriage",
                "id": 108,
                "day": "Monday",
                "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
            }, {
                "firstName": "Athena",
                "lastName": "Wisdoem",
                "id": 109,
                "day": "Sunday",
                "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I then have a swift file called Customer:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Customer: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    var staff: [Person]
    
    struct Person: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable  {
        var day: String
        var firstName: String
        var lastName: String
        var id: Int
        var phoneNumber: String
    }
}
```

Then I have another swift file called `ModelData`:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

var customers: [Customer] = load("customerData.json")
var person: [Customer.Person] = load("customerData.json")
```

Then I have a swift UIView called Dashboard. This is where I want to display the lists. There is a filtered list already in Dashboard.swift. There is some commented out Code of the filter that does not work.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Dashboard: View {
    @State var person = [Customer.Person]()

    var filterdRoutes:[Customer.Person]{
        person.filter() { filteredCustomer in
          (filteredCustomer.day == "Tuesday")
        }
    }

    var filterdTech:[Customer]{
        customers.filter { filteredCustomer in
            (filteredCustomer.name == "Michael")        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(filterdTech) { department in
                    Section(header: Text(department.name)){
                                ForEach(filterdRoutes) { filter1 in

                        NavigationLink(destination: RouteDetail(person: filter1)) {
                            RouteRow(person: filter1)
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFbkA.png)

Comment: _There is some commented out Code of the filter that does not work._, is this the only problem description we get? I have read the question and looked at the code but I don't understand what exactly it is that isn't working.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your question is.  Can you be clearer and more concise, ideally providing a minimum reproducablel example of the issue rather than all your code (of which I assume much isn't directly relevant to the issue)?

Comment: Sorry, I had tried to reduce the code before I put it in. I didn't know if you needed to see the data I was parsing. In order to catch my mistake. The problem is in the last section of Code. The Function filterdRoutes does not filter correctly. I want it to filter out Person when Day does not equal "Tuesday"